# Is a linear map from spaces of equal dimension guaranteed to be injective if it is surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given two vector spaces A and B that have an equal number of dimensions, is any linear map from A to B that is surjective also guaranteed to be injective?

Comment: When you say $A$ and $B$ have equal dimension, do you mean that $A$ and $B$ have equal *finite* dimension? If so, are you aware of the Rank-Nullity theorem?

Comment: Yes I did mean finite. I'm just learning about linear maps so I haven't heard of most theorems in this space. I'll read up on the Rank-Nullity theorem.

Comment: Just as a comment, since noone explicited mentioned an example in the non-finite case: the left-shift (or "forgets-first-coordinate" function) on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is obviously surjective and obviously not injective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ have the same (finite) dimension, a linear map is surjective if, and only if, is injective. If $\phi:A\longrightarrow B$ is a linear map, then $$dim(A)=dim(ker(\phi))+dim(Im(\phi)).$$ Therefore, $\phi$ is surjective if, and only if, $\phi$ is injective.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It follows from Rank-Nullity Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Hint 1: Being of finite dimension is a necessary hypothesis. Hint 2: Regular functions between sets of the same size have the property injective iff. surjective.

Use the finite basis!

Comment: Wondering what the down votes are for....